# How to create a combobox WITHOUT Windows Forms

Tags: c#, combobox

I am doing a web application in Visual Studio in C#. The application should be able to write out students and courses which they attend. Anyway, I added a "Create view", where I can create new courses, but now I want to add a COMBOBOX there so that I am able to choose students and for the chosen one enter a new course. Can somebody tell me how to add a combobox WITHOUT using Windows Forms? I need code, and explanation where to insert it! I hope you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: is it an asp.net application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `<select>` in html,to fill your list and dynamically create you need to fill your list in your controller like this:

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
Student std = new Student();
....
students.Add(std);
```

Then return your View and pass it your list:

```
return View(students);
```

In your View set your View Model like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<Student>
```

Then add a foreach loop and create your comboBox:

```
<select id="studentList">
foreach(Student s in Model)
{

  <option>@s.Name</option>
}
</select>
```

Or you can use `Html.DropDownListFor`Helper method, and it will create a list automatically for you:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Name)
```

I give you a sample,you can change it like whatever you want,you didn't provide enough information...

Answer (score 1):

Since I read that you did the "Create View" action, I assume you're making a web application in the ASP.NET MVC framework. A combobox on the web is merely this:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

-> Each "option" tag represents a choice in the dropdown.
Reference & more info on the "select" tag: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

But for full guidance on how to use the MVC framework I'd recommend you'd start a tutorial of some sorts, for example this one: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not ASP.net specific, rather its part of html.  The input control you're looking for is the [select](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) element.  If you're using MVC, you can use the [DropdownListFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) extension method.

If you're using other server technologies they may have their own html rendering helpers.